# split string to columns with content fill

Tags: sas

I have data that looks like this:

```
ID    Sequence
---------------------------------
101   E6S,K11T,Q174K,D177E
102   K11T,V245EKQ
```

I need to add:

1. A new column with column heading for each sequence, add prefix 'RT', drop the letters following the numeric part of the sequence
2. Fill the new column with the letters that follow the numeric part
   of the sequence

I need to create this:

```
ID    Sequence                RTE6   RTK11   RTQ174   RTD177   RTV245
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
101   E6S,K11T,Q174K,D177E    S      T       K        E
102   K11T,V245EKQ                   T                         EKQ
```

Comment: please post what you have tried so far. Look into the SCAN() function and proc transpose.

Comment: It's easier to read when you put the data in-line with the question as I've done above. @Reeza is correct, you'll need SCAN and transpose. Please post back when you've had an attempt at something we can help you with.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem a while ago. The code is adapted to your problem.

If found this solution to work faster than anything I tried with proc transpose.
Still overall performance on huge datasets (espc. using many different sequences) is not great at all, as we loop 2*2 over all strings and also the final variables.

Can anyone offer a faster solution?

(Caution: MacroVar is limited to 65534 Characters.)

```
data var_name ;
    set in_data;
    length var string $30.;
    do i = 1 to countw(Sequence, ',');
        string = scan(Sequence,i,',');
        var = substr(string,1,anydigit(string,-99));
        output;
        keep var;
    end;
run;
proc sql noprint; 
    select distinct compress("RT"||var) into :var_list separated by ' '
        from var_name;
quit;
%put &var_list.;
data out_data;
    set in_data;
    length string &var_list.  $30. n 8. ;
    array a_var [*] &var_list.;
    do i = 1 to countw(Sequence, ',');
        string = scan(Sequence,i,',');
        do j = 1 to dim(a_var);
            n = anydigit(string,-99) ;
            if substr(vname(a_var[j]),3) eq substr(string,1,n) then a_var[j] = substr(string,n+1);
        end;
    end;
    drop string i j n;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want a SAS data set and not a report.  ANYDIGIT makes it pretty easy to find the last non-digit sub-string.

```
data seq;
   infile cards firstobs=3;
   input id:$3. sequence :$50.;
   cards;
ID    Sequence
---------------------------------
101   E6S,K11T,Q174K,D177E
102   K11T,V245EKQ
;;;;
   run;
proc print;
   run;
data seq2V / View=seq2V;
   set seq;
   length w name sub $32 subl 8;
   do i = 1 by 1;
      w = scan(sequence,i,',');
      if missing(w) then leave;
      subl = anydigit(w,-99);
      name = substrn(w,1,subl);
      sub = substrn(w,subl+1);
      output;
      end;
   run;
proc transpose data=seq2V out=seq3(drop=_name_) prefix=RT;
   by id sequence;
   var sub;
   id name;
   run;
proc print;
   run;
```

[image]